# Setting up Parse on android studio

Tags: android

First step I had to open up the Parse starter project. So I clicked the root build.gradle file as stated on the website

I have two src packages. One in the root and another one inside the ParserStarterProject.Im supposed to add my initialization key to ParseApplication.java but I dont have that. I only have MainAcitivity and StarterApplication. I really dont know how to setup Parse as the website instructions doesn't match my project at all

Answer (score 0):

You can include your parse key in starter application or more easy way go to the parse site select project and download the project it automatically include your key in the starter application.

Go to starter application and check parse.initialize